Cropping an inserted image around the center
This answer is great, and gives me lots of ideas, but I'm hoping for still more. I'd like to write
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=4cm]{filename.png}

to get a 5:4 ratio image from my filename...but I'd like to do it by cropping rather than distorting the source image. What I need is to

keep all the pixels in the vertical direction

trim an equal number of columns of pixels from the left and right to
get the right aspect ratio.


Thus if the input is 200 pixels tall and 200 pixels wide, I'd like to remove the left 20 and the right 20 columns of pixels to get something 200 tall x 160 wide, and then display this in a 5cm tall x 4 cm wide space.
When I talk about "removing rows of pixels", I'm speaking figuratively -- I mean that this is the area of the image that I'd like to crop.
To keep things simple, let's assume that the input image width is always at least 4/5 of the height. (This gets rid of a lot of ugly cases, etc.)
So I want to trim, from both the left and right sides of the image
(w - (4/5)h)/2 = (w/2) - (2/5)h
where w and h are the width and height of the image.

please provide a minimal working example for people to test with. what have you tried?

Note that pixels make no real sense here. Might be easier to crop like that in an external tool.

cfr: I was mimicking the form of the  much-cited  question that I linked to (and which sam carter helpfully pointed me to again). TBH, I didn't know how to include an example that wants to load an image, because I didn't know how to load a sample image (although I've now learned from Werner's helpful answer).

This is easily achievable using \includegraphics' trim and clip option, together with an expandable calculation of the reduction via \fpeval.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\imgbox

\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertImageFiveByFour}{ m }{%
  \savebox{\imgbox}{\includegraphics{example-image}}% Store image in box
  \resizebox{!}{5cm}{%
    \includegraphics
      [trim=\fpeval{\wd\imgbox/2 - (2/5)*\ht\imgbox}pt 0pt \fpeval{\wd\imgbox/2 - (2/5)*\ht\imgbox}pt 0pt,
       clip]
      {#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% Original image
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image}% Maintain aspect ratio

\bigskip

% Expected output based on 5:4 height:width aspect ratio
\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=4cm]{example-image}

\bigskip

% Clipped output
\savebox{\imgbox}{\includegraphics{example-image}}% Store image in box
\resizebox{!}{5cm}{%
  \includegraphics
    [trim=\fpeval{\wd\imgbox/2 - (2/5)*\ht\imgbox}pt 0pt \fpeval{\wd\imgbox/2 - (2/5)*\ht\imgbox}pt 0pt,
     clip]
    {example-image}%
}

\bigskip

% Using macro
\InsertImageFiveByFour{example-image}

\end{document}

The above \InsertImageFiveByFour assumes the aspect ratio is 5:(4+), meaning the image is wider than 4 units for its height of 5 units. That is, it's trimmable from the sides. You can, of course, measure this first and then condition on whether or not to trim.

Thanks. It was the "fpeval" thing that was eluding me. (Every time I need to do arithmetic in LaTeX I suffer a good deal of anxiety.) I really appreciate your very complete example.

Why not dimeval?

@egreg: Oooo, a new function I haven't used that before. Sure, that's a more direct option.

A LaTeX3 attempt, inspired by this answer, using the l3box module:
\cs_new_protected:Npn \john_trim_sides:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \leavevmode
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim
      {
        \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box - \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box*#3/#2
      }
    \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box
      {0.5\l_tmpa_dim}
      {0pt}
      {0.5\l_tmpa_dim}
      {0pt}
    \box_set_clipped:N \l_tmpa_box
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  }

with a user command \trimsides allowing to change the ratio with \trimside[H:W]{content}
\ExpandArgs {ne} \NewDocumentCommand \trimsides
  {
    >{ \SplitArgument {1} {\c_colon_str} }
    O {5 \c_colon_str 4} m
  }
  {%
    \john_trim_sides:nnn {#2} #1
  }

(\ExpandArgs and \c_colon_str are needed here because the colon catcode is altered with expl3).
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ExpandArgs {ne} \NewDocumentCommand \trimsides
  {
    >{ \SplitArgument {1} {\c_colon_str} }
    O {5 \c_colon_str 4} m
  }
  {%
    \john_trim_sides:nnn {#2} #1
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \john_trim_sides:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    \leavevmode
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim
      {
        \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box - \box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box*#3/#2
      }
    \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l_tmpa_box
      {0.5\l_tmpa_dim}
      {0pt}
      {0.5\l_tmpa_dim}
      {0pt}
    \box_set_clipped:N \l_tmpa_box
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}

\medskip

\trimsides{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}

\medskip

\trimsides[4:5]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}

\end{document}



What we can do in OpTeX:

\def\clipinpic#1#2#3{%
   \setbox0=\hbox to#1{\picheight=#2\hss\inspic{#3}\hss}%
   {\roundness=0pt \clipinoval .5\wd0 .5\ht0 \wd0 \ht0 {\box0}}%
}

\clipinpic{4cm}{5cm}{example-image.png}

\bye

